# Django Testing Existence of File as URL

Tags: django, testing, tdd

I am trying to figure out how to test for existence of files as URLs in Django. The version below version produces a failure:

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 302 != 200
```

Here is the code for the test.

```
from django.test import Client 
from django.utils import translation

class ExistenceTest(TestCase):
    def test_static_css_directory_exists(self):
        C = Client()
        response = C.get('/static/css/clean-blog.min.css')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

This is the response object. Somehow, the language gets in the way or so it seems.

```
<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/en/static/css/clean-blog.min.css/">
```

When I launch a server via `runserver`, I am able to navigate to `http://localhost:8000/static/css/clean-blog.min.css/` successfully and see the file in the browser. If I try `http://localhost:8000/en/static/css/clean-blog.min.css/`, I get an error (404 in the browser, but it is probably what produces 302).

Comment: A 302 is a redirect. It might be a good idea to look to where it redirects.

Comment: I have made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you appended static file to the urlpatterns  in the url file like below :

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
...

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

at the end of setting.py add these lines:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
```

before you run the test visite your URL ('/static/css/clean-blog.min.css') and check that (is it accessible? or not)

I hope this solution be helpful for you

Comment: The static files are being served. That is not the issue. Testing properly is :)

Comment: I can access my static file in the URL using this simple solution. test your URL too( for extra trace remove slash (/) at the beginning of your static URL pass).

Comment: That is not an issue, and it appears that you may be misunderstanding the question.